# System migration - need advice choosing new platform

Tags: javascript, migration, spreadsheet, crm

I am a spanish speaker I will try my best in English I hope I made myself clear enough.
During many years I have been working on a spreadsheet (google sheets) for a company, to be used as the main database and management system, where you can find customer info, you can see all the purchases made by that client, you can get a list of clients that need to be reached, you can find the prices list for the products, product information, you can use it to input the orders, print every order and track it until delivery and payment, and the order itself also feeds stock, create an order to refill stock,
It is also used to calculate the payment for the salesmen, create statistics and get sales trends, etc. It includes almost everything the client needs, it's pretty cool. Everything created in google sheets. No macros needed so far.
The thing is that now the client needs to make the same system but more friendly to be used for non experienced people (almost none IT knowdledge, I mean, at all!).
I am not sure what platform should I choose to create this system, it will be starting over, but I cannot wait to start working on this new chalenge.
The good thing is that I have now some knowdledge in JS and I am learning also HTML and the tools to develop web pages. Not sure if I can use any of these to work on this project. What do you recommend? Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have "paragraphs" in Spanish?

Comment: Hi Jaromanda X, I am not sure I understand your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is fairly vague, but I'll try to recommend something despite that.

Since you said you'll be "starting over", it sounds like you wouldn't necessarily have to use a Google Sheet.

This is a fairly difficult undertaking for someone inexperienced, especially since it's being developed for a client, but I'd recommend:

- Use a SQL DB like Postgres to store the data.
- Use something like Express to handle requests, and render pages.
- Use some basic HTML+CSS+JS to make nice-looking pages.

And just build a web-app.

You could go other routes, (i.e. keep the "DB" in Google Sheets and use the [Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api), and just use HTML+JS+CSS on static pages), so don't take my opinion as the only route

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer!! The client is the company I manage, so I am the client myself.. and I am delegating all the spreadsheet usage to new employees to have more time to programming.

Comment: I want to thank you so much for your answer, it sounds like something I can do! Sadly SQL I dont know but I think I could make some research and training myself on it, or, as you said, keeping it in Google sheets. it was the answer I was looking for to understand were to start! thank you so much